# Supervised Classification within the bounds of a FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, features, classification, image-classification

I am a bit new to classification within GEE and was hoping to get some help regarding classifying within a specific region.

```
var bands = ['NDVI'];

var landSat = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate('2014-5-01', '2014-5-10')
  .select(bands)
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
  .first());

var landSatTest = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI')
  .filterBounds(MY FEATURE COLLECTION POLYGONS)
  .filterDate('2014-5-01', '2014-5-10')
  .select(bands)
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
  .first());

//Merging imports of sample regions into one feature collection 
var trainingFC = not_fallowed.merge(fallowed);

//Training data
var training = landSat.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: trainingFC,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
});

//Random Forest Classifier Training
var trained = ee.Classifier.randomForest().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover', 
  inputProperties: bands
});

//Run classification 
var classified = landSatTest.select(bands).classify(trained);

//Displaying results
Map.centerObject(iqROI, 7.5);

//70FF00 (green) not fallowed, FF2D000 (red) fallowed
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['70FF00', 'FF2D00']}, 
'classification');
```

So rather than defining a new ROI within landSatTest I would like to apply it to my FeatureCollection in order to only classify that area as I am only interested in that area's outputs. Otherwise it seems I get an area that adds a lot of extra space.